# lineto draws relative to window not canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm experimenting with using drawing function on Canvas and I was curious to see if anyone can suggest a solution as I'm new to this ;)

My main html pages have a couple of Canvases set up, in layers so that I can manipulate and erase each without interfering with the others. I have something like this:

```
<div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="450" height="450" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<canvas id="layer1" width="450" height="450" style="position: absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:1;"></canvas>
<canvas id="layer2" width="450" height="450" style="position: absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:2;"></canvas>
<canvas id="layer3" width="450" height="450" style="position: absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:3;"></canvas>
<canvas id="layer4" width="450" height="450" style="position: absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:4;"></canvas>
</div>
```

In a bit of Javascript, I am manipulating these canvases such as:

```
c1=document.getElementById("layer1");
ctx1=c1.getContext("2d");
ctx1.beginPath();
ctx1.moveTo(this.xcoord, this.ycoord);
ctx1.lineTo(newx, newy);
ctx1.stroke();
```

Now this works; it draws the lines on screen with no problem, except that they are not being drawn on the canvas, they are being drawn relative to the main browser window (my canvases are not at the top left of the screen but a little way down due to text and other graphics).
Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: UM what is `"style="position: absolute; left:0; top:0;"`doing? That is your problem, it is putting it on the top left corner! Set the background color red or inspect the element! http://jsfiddle.net/yt22u/

Comment: Hi,
When I do
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
to draw a trial red rectangle in the ctx1 associated with canvas1. But when I remove the style declarations you highly above, the lineto segments not appear to the right of the original myCanvas, whereas I'm trying to stack them on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

It is realtive to the browser because you told it to be relative to the browser. You need to make the wrapper element's position relative.

**CSS:**

```
div.wrapper { position:relative;}
div.wrapper canvas { position : absolute; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="450" height="450" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="layer1" width="450" height="450" style="z-index:1;background-color: red"></canvas>
    <canvas id="layer2" width="450" height="450" style="z-index:2;background-color:yellow;"></canvas>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/X8BCp/1/

Comment: Thanks. This seems to solve that problem! Its part of a legacy webpage that I am trying to maintain: the canvases should appear inside a table element, with another table element next to it. The canvases overwrite the next table element along, which makes sense with the canvas wrappers being set to absolute. Do you know how I get rid of this problem?

Basically its
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>The canvas stuff above
    </td>
    <td>more stuff
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

Comment: Sorry formatting of the html didn't work properly in that, but hopefully you can see what it say ;)